# Express the mathematical constant $e$ in terms of a limit that goes to zero.

Tags: calculus, limits, constants

The mathematical expression of the mathematical constant $e$ in terms of a limit that goes to infinity is $$e = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

But can we express the mathematical constant $e$ in terms of a limit that goes to zero; $e=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow 0} ...$?

Thank you.

(problem from book of Spivak)

Comment: Do you $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{h\to\frac1a}f\left(\frac1h\right)$$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?
$$\lim_{n\to 0}(1+n)^{1/n}=e$$

Comment: But is it true?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: Love you man!! thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome! I like your question.

Comment: @mathlove Just a tip: $$\begin{array}{cc}
\mathrm{Bad} & \mathrm{Better} \\
\hline \\
e^{i\frac{\pi}2} \quad e^{\frac{i\pi}2}& e^{i\pi/2} \\
\lim_{n\to0}(1+n)^{\frac1n} & \lim_{n\to0}(1+n)^{1/n} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @Adobe: Thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: @mathlove You're welcome! ;-)

Comment: Naming a variable $n$ if it  $\to 0$ may however be confusing. Also, the meaning of $(1+n)^{1/n}$ may be probelmatic for arbirtary $n\approx 0$, esp. when some define such arbitrary powers only via $e$.

Comment: Yes, it should be $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}.$